# Is there a performance benefit to repeating a WHERE filter in subqueries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```sql
WITH prices AS (
  SELECT itemId
       , monthId
       , MIN(lastPrice / firstPrice) AS gain
  FROM (
    SELECT *
         , FIRST_VALUE(price) OVER (PARTITION BY monthId
                                    ORDER BY date) AS firstPrice
         , LAST_VALUE(price)  OVER (PARTITION BY monthId
                                    ORDER BY date) AS lastPrice
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM  foo
        WHERE monthId = 82      -- a repeat of the final WHERE
    ) x
  ) x
  WHERE firstPrice != 0
    AND lastPrice  != 0
  GROUP BY itemId
         , monthId
)
SELECT f.monthId
     , f.itemId
     , p.gain
FROM      foo f
LEFT JOIN prices p
       ON f.itemId = p.itemId
      AND f.monthId = p.monthId
WHERE gain IS NOT NULL
  AND monthId = 82              -- repeated above
```

As noted, the full query ends with a `WHERE monthId = 82` clause, which is also present in the `prices` subquery.

If I remove the `WHERE` from the subquery, the result is the same. This makes sense since the result would be naturally constrained by the final `WHERE`.

However, the case without the subquery `WHERE` runs dramatically slower (40 vs. 3 minutes). However, I'm not proficient enough at SQL to know if this is expected or if it's merely an artifact of statistics (I've run the version with the subquery `WHERE` many, many times already and only now tried to remove it).

It'd make sense for this to improve performance since it allows the server to only perform the operations within `prices` (there are many more in my real case) on the subset of rows with `monthId = 82`. However, I don't know if the compiler already optimizes the subquery to filter it with that subset regardless and therefore the benefit I'm seeing is merely an illusion.

---

<sub>For the record, my actual `FIRST/LAST_VALUE` calls have `ROWS BETWEEN PRECEEDING UNBOUNDED AND FOLLOWING UNBOUNDED`, just omitted them to simplify the query.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Server optimizer is smart enough to push `where` filters into subqueries under many circumstances.  However, optimizers make mistakes and they miss situations -- as would appear to be the case here.  In general, you can check the query plan to see if it makes a difference.

I would be inclined to repeat the logic, just to be sure that the query is as efficient as possible.